# Sorting in Data fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I have very simple queries around Data Fusion and the ETL transformation capabilities:

1. How do you sort a file in data fusion using a particular column/columns? Couldn't find any plugin or any directive in wrangler.
2. How do you perform a cumulative aggregation?

Comment: You can perform aggregation by using `group-by` plugin in the analytics section of the Data Fusion UI.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understood the use case, but I'll answer to the best of my understanding and knowledge.

1. If you're looking to sort records from an input set, then hopefully the [TopN plugin](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/710508622/Top-N+Analytics) (which can be deployed from the Hub) will be useful to you. You could try to use it in conjunction with other plugins (in case you wish to output records to a file for example). In regards to Wrangler - I also couldn't find that Wrangler has a sorting operation available currently (see cheatsheet [here](https://github.com/data-integrations/wrangler/blob/develop/wrangler-docs/cheatsheet.md), ‘develop’ branch).
2. As Sakshi also suggested, you could use the [Group by plugin](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/515211360/Group+By+Analytics) in the Analytics section of Data Fusion UI to perform aggregations.

For reference, Cloud Data Fusion plugins list is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/plugins).

If this is not what you are looking for, then it’ll be helpful if you could share more about your use case and maybe provide an example of the input vs output.